# Does Python have a non-greedy parsing option?

Tags: python, parsing

Some dynamic languages have non-greedy versions of code parsing. E.g. Julia has,

```
julia> Meta.parse("(x=1)@blahblah", 1, greedy=false)
(:(x = 1), 6)
```

which parses only the first expression encountered, stopping before the `@blahblah` (which in this case wouldn't even form valid code together with the first part).

Does Python have anything similar?

I suppose I could loop through calling `compile` and adding one character at a time to the string until I don't get a syntax error, although that seems quite wasteful...

Comment: Does regex count?

Comment: No, here I'm asking about parsing full Python expressions, which can't be done with regex's alone.

Answer (score 1):

Pyparsing will parse fairly complex expressions, and the default behavior is to stop once the parser rules find nothing else to parse. For instance, if you assume that your leading section is just some arbitrary string of nested parentheses, you could use pyparsing's built-in `nestedExpr` parser:

```
>>> import pyparsing as pp
>>> s = "(x=1)@blahblah"
>>> print(pp.nestedExpr().parseString(s))
[['x=1']]
```

A more complete example might be:

```
ppc = pp.pyparsing_common
assignment_expr = ppc.identifier + '=' + ppc.number
fn_call = ppc.identifier + pp.nestedExpr() # lazy definition of arg list in ()'s

# a woefully incomplete parser for Python statements
statement_expression = fn_call | assignment_expr

LPAR, RPAR = map(pp.Suppress, "()")
prefix = LPAR + statement_expression + RPAR
print(prefix.parseString(s))
```

Note: I am the author of pyparsing.

Comment: Thanks this looks nearly perfect! I'm curious just reading about pyparser now, this is not specific to Python syntax right? Is there any Python syntax your above code snippet would fail on? Or any invalid Python code which it would allow?

Comment: This example is absolutely *not* about Python syntax. I just used `nestedExpr` since it was a quick-and-dirty sample that would parse your example string, to show you that pyparsing's default behavior is non-greedy. But as I stated above, it will parse *any* string with nested parentheses, valid Python or not. If you want to parse (or limit what you match) specific Python expressions, you have some work ahead of you, to define that with pyparsing's classes.

Comment: See my edit showing the inclusion of some simple Python statements